# Is there a way to improve the code quality by injecting/importing a service into a class that is not a component/service/repository?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, nestjs, code-cleanup

In this example, I will be using 2 files ( LogService and LoggedConflictException ).

I would like to inject LogService into LoggedConflictException class, instead of passing it via the constructor or method of LoggedConflictException. This is what I do now (and I don't like it at all):

```
export class LoggedConflictException extends ConflictException {

    constructor( logService: LogService, options?: { 
        purpose?: string, 
        credentials?: any, 
        message?: string | object | any, 
        error?: string 
    } ) {
        super( options.message );

        // the fact that I have to pass logService instance every time does make me worry.
        // I would like to inject logService directly without the need to pass it down from other classes.
        logService.createLog( options.purpose, options.message, options.credentials, options.error );
    }
}
```

And this is how I pass down the logService instance from my controller:

```
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {

    constructor( private logService: LogService ) {}

    @Post( '/test' )
    test(): Promise<any> {
        const options = { 
            purpose: LOG_PURPOSE.TEST, 
            message: EXCEPTION_MESSAGE.TEST_MESSAGE 
        };
        throw new LoggedConflictException( this.logService, options ); // <- I don't like to pass this.logService every time when I want to log and throw an exception!
        // instead I want to have a code that looks like this:
        throw new LoggedConflictException( options );
    }

}
```

I hope that my question makes sense and that someone can help any person who struggles to have a clean code just like me.

Comment: Why pass a class instance to an exception instead of throwing the exception and having a filter worry about the logging of the exception. The exception in general should just have information about what went wrong.

Comment: Because my intention was to log issues and throw it at the same time. I don't like to Log and then throw. Instead, I would like to pass the message to my custom class that is extending any exception, Log it into the db and then throw the exception to the client. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but if you're looking for code cleanup and an easier time with working with your code, I think setting the message in the exception and logging it from the filter is the way to go. This way the logger is instantiated by nest via dependency injection and the only thing you as a developer are worrying about from there is setting the correct message in the exception you are throwing. The flow would then be, throw exception -> catch exception -> log error

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Would you be so kind to share an example for me to see? Honestly, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: sure, [here is my original set of filters](https://github.com/jmcdo29/zeldaPlay/tree/deployment/src/server/app/filters) where `super.catch(excpetion)` was an implementation to log every error that came through. I've since started to re-write my server and don't have a current example, but hopefully this can give you an idea

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Very much appreciated Jay!